# Deleting a directory on exit in Java

Tags: java, directory

I was just wondering if it was possible to delete a directory when the application was closed?

Is there an easy way to do something when the application is closed?

Currently my app downloads the class files at runtime so what I'm really looking for is something to remove them from the clients system.

I've tried so far

```
File directory = new File("macros/bin/");
directory.deleteOnExit();
```

As well as a delete on runtime of the downloaded startup files (which obviously can't be done seeing as it needs them in order to run).

Comment: If these class files are loaded in JVM then MS Windows will probably not let you deleted them

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        /* Delete your file here. */
      }
 });
```

A lot depends on how your program is ending.

Comment: on most systems the shutdown hook runs on every instance but `kill -9` which is expected behavior.

Comment: You should probably contribute it to Apache commons-io since I think your implementation better reflects the actual needs. The current implementation of commons-io is to register the files that are in the directory at the time of the call rather than at the end once all the processing is completed.

Comment: There is a missing rounded bracket in your code, and for some weird reason SO does not allow me to correct that...

Answer (score 17):

You should do the following using [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(fileOrDir)));
```

Note: the FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit implementation is flawed:
it registers files for deletion during registration of the directory,
thus if files are added later it will fail to delete the directory.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, the javadoc says that `directory.deleteOnExit()` should work ... the method supposedly works for directories.  However, approach is probably failing because the directory is not empty at the point it tries to delete it ... and the OS typically won't let you delete a non-empty directory.

The solution would be to call `deleteOnExit()` for the files that the user downloads too.  You have to do this *after* the `directory.deleteOnExit()` call.  See the javadoc for why.

Having said that, the explicit shutdown hook is a more robust approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this: `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit(File)`

```
/*
 * Schedules a file to be deleted when JVM exits.
 * If file is directory delete it and all sub-directories.
 */
FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit(File)
```

**Limitation:**
Unfortunately this only works if NO additional files and/or folders are created inside the directory after `forceDeleteOnExit` was called.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
A recursive function.

```
public static void makeVolatile(File folder)
{
    folder.deleteOnExit();
    for(File f : folder.listFiles())
    {
        if(f.isDirectory())
            makeVolatile(f);
        else
            f.deleteOnExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't delete newly added files.