# Not Able to delete a clone local folder from remote repository using Java

Tags: java, git, apache-commons, jgit

I am not able to delete a folder where I have cloned a remote github repository.

My code is as below.

```
public class JGitDemo {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        try {

            String localFolder="F:/demojavarepo";
            Git.cloneRepository().setURI("https://github.com/skeeto/sample-java-project")
                    .setDirectory(new File(localFolder)).setBranch("master").call();

            // Some Processing on the  cloned directory

            FileUtils.forceDelete(new File(localFolder));

            //FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(localFolder));

            //FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(localFolder));

            //FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit(new File(localFolder));

        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, after cloning the repo, I do some processing on it and then finally I want to remove the local folder.

But, I get the below error, when I try to delete the folder.

```
  java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: F:\demojavarepo\.git\objects\pack\pack-b7dc7f9db205afdbdfbb7608f098c2ee38fb4875.pack
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2400)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1721)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1617)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2391)
    at repoclient.JGitDemo.main(JGitDemo.java:22)
```

I am using Apache Commons IO **FileUtils** Class **forceDelete** method. I
event tried other methods on FileUtils Class but am not able to have the folders deleted.

I am using JGit api to clone a repository in a folder using java.

Should I disconnect or in some way disassociate the local git folder from remote git in some way for deletion to happen successfully.

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the Git repo. As your code stands, you're throwing away the reference. I suggest using a temp directory to clone into, so that you don't have to delete it, the OS will. See various `createTempDirectory` methods in [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

```
Git git = Git.cloneRepository...
try {
    // whatever
} finally {
    if (git != null) git.close();
}
```

If you must delete the dir yourself, do it after `git.close()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165253/deleting-a-directory-on-exit-in-java) thread for how to do it on JVM exit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. git.close() resolved the issue.